# Search the text inside a variable for a certain term, php

Tags: php

1. I am pulling profiles which mention the word "fitness" from a database like so:

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT profile FROM ".$table." WHERE profile LIKE ('fitness')");
   ```
2. I am doing a basic retrieval of the `$profile` variable and echo it.

   ```
   while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $profile = $slice['profile'];
       echo $profile;
   }
   ```

What I'd like is a way to search the text inside `$profile` for the word "fitness" and highlight the found word using maybe CSS.

Any ideas how?

**UPDATE:**

Ty very much, and I have one more problem.

In the sql query I will have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT profile FROM ".$table." WHERE $profile_rule");

$profile_rule = 'profile LIKE ('fitness') AND profile LIKE ('pets')';
```

Is there a way to s**trip the $profile_rule** and get just the **words fitness and pets**? Maybe strip everything which isn't encased by '' ?

Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function highlightWord($word, $text){
    return str_replace($word, '<span class="highlighted">' . $word . '</span>', $text);
}

$profile = highlightWord('fitness', $profile);
```

**EDIT**: Per your update, take a look at the `IN()` operator:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT profile FROM $table WHERE profile IN ('fitness','pets')");
```

**EDIT 2**: I think I misunderstood your question, though I still recommend edit 1. If you just want to grab the words `fitness` and `pets` from that `$profile_rule` string, use some simple regex:

```
preg_match_all("|[a-z]+(?=\'\)|","profile LIKE ('fitness') AND profile LIKE ('pets')", $profiles);
var_dump($profiles); // array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "fitness" [1]=> string(4) "pets" } }
```

Comment: Ty very much, ty ty ty:) can you please look at the update of the question, maybe you can give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile = str_replace("fitness", "<span style=\"color:red\">fitness</span>",
           $slice["profile"]);
```